# Iterate through subfolder in list via CAML & Powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, caml-query

I have a need to remove unique permissions on documents in a list, however, the list is over 5000 items so the following won't work, and its SharePoint Online so I can't change the threshold.

```
$ctx=New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext("https://www.example.com/subSite/")

$password = ConvertTo-SecureString -string "MyPassword" -AsPlainText -Force

$ctx.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials("admin@mytenant", $password)

$ll=$ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Company Docs")
  $ctx.Load($ll)
  $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
  $spQuery = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery

  $spQuery.ViewXml ="<View Scope='Recursive' />";


  $itemki=$ll.GetItems($spQuery) 
  $ctx.Load($itemki)
  $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
  for($j=0;$j -lt $itemki.Count ;$j++)

  {
      $itemki[$j].ResetRoleInheritance()
      $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
  }
```

As an alternative, if I can specify a sub-folder I have a chance of getting this working.

Something like:

```
$spQuery.FolderServerRelativeUrl= "/SubSite/Company Docs/Folder1/"
```

I can't seem to get this to work though, any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into SPQuery paging with CSOM:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/18606.sharepoint-2013-paging-with-sharepoint-client-object-model.aspx
Using:

```
var pageInfo = "Paged=TRUE&p_ID=<ID last of ListItem>;"
var position = new SP.ListItemCollectionPosition();
position.set_pagingInfo(pageInfo);
camlQuery.set_listItemCollectionPosition(position);
```